# Non-parametric or parametric t-test: which one to trust?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, nonparametric

I have two simple bimodal distributions that I'm sampling from, and I know that they are actually exactly the same. In my setting, I collect one sample from each and compare them, i.e., I'm doing a two-sample test where each sample is independent of the other.

When I use a standard parametric t-test like the Welch's t-test, I'm getting a false positive rate of 0.004. However, when I use the non-parametric Mann-Whitney U rank test, I'm getting a false positive of 0.07. In both cases, I used a p-value cutoff of 0.05, so it's very weird that Welch's t-test is doing much better than it needs to be.

In both cases, I'm using a good implementation provided by Scipy.

Should I trust the non-parametric or the parametric t-test for this one? I'm kind of confused.

Comment: The Wilcoxon test is not a nonparametric t-test; there is no such thing.  The Wilcoxon test is a nonparametric test aimed at determining whether values from one population tend to be larger than values from another.  To get the "false positive" probability you would have to run a simulation.  What was your simulation setup, i.e., what assumptions did you make for population distribution which is assumed to be the same for both groups?  Any why use p-value cutoffs?  This is arbitrary and virtually meaningless.

Comment: I think there is perhaps arguably such a thing as a 'nonparametric t-test', in the sense that you can use the t-statistic applied to the data in a nonparametric test (say a permutation test or a bootstrap test), and still be testing a hypothesis about means. I agree that the rank sum test (or its equivalents) isn't one, though.

Comment: @FrankHarrell I'm not talking about the Wilcoxon test, and in Scipy there is actually a different function for it. I'm strictly referring to Mann-Whitney U rank test: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu.html.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Indeed, I'm running a simulation of 1000 trials. The two population distributions are the same because I created them to be the same. The p-value cutoffs are used to determine whether the test result is significant.

Comment: The Wilcoxon two-sample rank-sum test and the Mann-Whitney test are equivalent.  The use of p-value cutoffs to declare 'significance' is not the best science.  Under the null hypothesis of equal distributions you should find that for the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test $\Pr(p < 0.05) = 0.05$.

Comment: @FrankHarrell "Under the null hypothesis of equal distributions you should find that for the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test Pr(<0.05)=0.05." - I totally agree. The focus of my question is more about understanding why Welch's t-test achieves a much lower FPR than it should - maybe because it's parametric and its assumptions are not satisfied? Also, what do you recommend as a better way to declare 'significance'?

Comment: Don't "declare significance".  Just provide the evidence against the supposition of no effect (continuous p-value if frequentist).  So you are finding that Welch's test has lower power.  That's to be expected as Welch's t-test assumes normality for each of the two groups of raw data, and you have a strong violation of normality.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Thanks for the confirmation. Just to double-check: so, in general, if I have no knowledge about the underlying populations (two populations in this case), I'm better off using the other "non-parametric" test?

Comment: Yes that's a good default